# How can i auto fill my inputfield when i use my select option

Tags: php, pdo

I have this select where i want to autofill the inputfields of Tolminus and Tolplus when i select an option. How can i do that?

This is what i have tried:

This is the table i am working with

```
+----+--------------+---------+----------+
| id |  Varenummer  | Tolplus | Tolminus |
+----+--------------+---------+----------+
|  1 | Varenummer 1 |     123 |     -123 |
|  2 | Varenummer 2 |     321 |     -321 |
+----+--------------+---------+----------+
```

Here is the code i've tried with

this is my class

```
public function getAllVarenummer(){
    return $this->db->tolist("SELECT Varenummer FROM `Varenummer_tb`");
}
```

This is my select and without the `WHERE Varenummer.id = Tolminus.id` i get the first value.

```
<select class="form-control" name="Varenummer" id="exampleFormControlSelect4" id="selectid">
    <?php foreach ($csv->getAllVarenummer() as $csv) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $csv->id ?>" selected><?= $csv->Varenummer ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>...

<?php
    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT `Tolminus`,Varenummer FROM Varenummer_tb WHERE Varenummer.id = Tolminus.id");
    $sth->execute();
    $Tolminus = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
?>

//Input fields

<div class="form-group col-2">
    <label for="Tolminus">Tol -</label>
    <?=$error['Tolminus']?>
    <input type="text" name="Tolminus" id="Tolminus" class="form-control" value="<?= $Tolminus ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-2">
    <label for="Tolplus">Tol +</label>
    <?=$error['Tolplus']?>
    <input type="text" name="Tolplus" id="Tolplus" class="form-control" value="<?= $_POST['Tolplus'] ?>">
</div>
```

The result should be when i select the Varenummer 1 the Tolplus input field would be 123 and the Tolminus would be -123.

to be more clear 
$csv is from the class.php

```
class Csv extends \PDO
{
    /**
     * @var null
     */
    private $db = null;

    /**
     * csv constructor.
     * @param $db
     */
    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

        /**
     * @param int $length
     * @return string
     */
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the condition to match the value fetch from the database table. Add the below line in the `<option>` tag.

```
  if ($csv->id == $_POST['Tolplus']){ 
      echo 'selected=selected' 
  }
```